# Java TelnetClient InputStream closed after open

Tags: java, inputstream, telnet

I am using Apache Commons TelnetClient to make an automated telnet interface for some switches. If I telnet to the switch directly from the machine, the connection never seems to time out. Randomly, in the Java program, the connection seems to close immediately along with the InputStream. I was trying to build a check that sees the connection failure and tries to make the connection again, but if it fails the first time, it always fails.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

  public String connect()
  {
     String errorMessage = null;
     tcConnectionHandle = new TelnetClient();
     tcConnectionHandle.setDefaultTimeout(iTimeOutMilliseconds);

     try
     {
        tcConnectionHandle.connect(strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort);
        osOutput = tcConnectionHandle.getOutputStream();
        isInput = tcConnectionHandle.getInputStream();
        int availableBytes = isInput.available();

        while(availableBytes <= 0)
        {
           tcConnectionHandle = null;
           isInput = null;
           osOutput = null;
           Thread.sleep(500);
           tcConnectionHandle = new TelnetClient();
           Thread.sleep(500);
           tcConnectionHandle.setDefaultTimeout(iTimeOutMilliseconds);
           Thread.sleep(500);
           tcConnectionHandle.connect(strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort);
           Thread.sleep(500);
           osOutput = tcConnectionHandle.getOutputStream();
           Thread.sleep(500);
           isInput = tcConnectionHandle.getInputStream();
           Thread.sleep(500);
           availableBytes = isInput.available();
           System.out.println("reopened: " + availableBytes);
        }
     }
     catch(InterruptedException iX)
     {
        errorMessage = "Could not establish connection. " + iX.getLocalizedMessage();
     }
     catch(SocketException sX)
     {
        errorMessage = sX.getMessage();
     }
     catch(IOException ioX)
     {
        errorMessage = ioX.getMessage();
     }

     return errorMessage;
  }
```

If I leave out the `Thread.sleep(500)` it will never have any availableBytes. With the pause, it has a result of 20, however, if I try to use `isInput.read()` it will return -1 which means the InputStream is closed.

I'm looking for a way to catch connection failures and try the connection again. It happens too frequently to not try again.

Comment: Why are you testing available bytes being negative or zero? What's the point of testing it at all? Who said there must be available data immediately you connect? Just do a read. It will block until data arrives. Use a read timeout to control that.

Comment: I was doing testing because the read was failing and returning -1 (as stated below my code block). It was not blocking until data arrived because the InputStream was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the InputStream attached to the TelnetClient was randomly in a closed state. Any attempts to read it while in that state made communication fail even if I created a new TelnetClient Object and reconnected to the same Telnet server later. It doesn't make sense, but I decided to try a new approach instead of figuring out what was happening in the TelnetClient class.

I solved the issue by using `implements TelnetInputListener` for this class. InputStream is occasionally null when `telnetInputAvailable()` is called, but I am able to recover from it now by not doing anything on that particular call to the function.

```
public String connect()
{
   String errorMessage = null;
   tcConnectionHandle = new TelnetClient();
   tcConnectionHandle.setDefaultTimeout(iTimeOutMilliseconds);
   tcConnectionHandle.registerInputListener(this);

   try
   {
      tcConnectionHandle.connect(strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort);
      osOutput = tcConnectionHandle.getOutputStream();
      isInput = tcConnectionHandle.getInputStream();
   }
   catch(SocketException sX)
   {
      errorMessage = sX.getMessage();
   }
   catch(IOException ioX)
   {
      errorMessage = ioX.getMessage();
   }

   return errorMessage;
}

public Matcher waitForRegularExpression(String regularExpression)
{
   Matcher matcher;
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)" + regularExpression);
   StringBuilder warningLog = new StringBuilder();

   synchronized(sbInputBuffer)
   {
      matcher = pattern.matcher(sbInputBuffer.toString());

      while(!matcher.find())
      {
         try
         {
            int inputBufferSize = sbInputBuffer.length();
            sbInputBuffer.wait(iTimeOutMilliseconds);

            if(inputBufferSize == sbInputBuffer.length())
            {
               warningLog.append("Did not find pattern and no new input.");
               logWarning(warningLog.toString());
               return null;
            }
         }
         catch(InterruptedException intX)
         {
            warningLog.append("Interrupted waiting on input. ").append(intX.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         matcher = pattern.matcher(sbInputBuffer.toString());
      }

      sbInputBuffer.delete(0, matcher.end()-1);
   }

   if(!warningLog.toString().isEmpty())
   {
      logWarning(warningLog.toString());
   }

   return matcher;
}

@Override
public void telnetInputAvailable()
{
   synchronized(sbInputBuffer)
   {
      StringBuilder warningLog = new StringBuilder();
      int readBytes = -2;

      if(isInput != null)
      {
         try
         {
            readBytes = isInput.read();

            if(readBytes > 0)
            {
               sbInputBuffer.append((char)readBytes);
            }

            sbInputBuffer.notify();
         }
         catch(IOException ioX)
         {
            warningLog.append("Failed for IO: ").append(ioX.getLocalizedMessage()).append(" - input so far: ")
               .append(sbInputBuffer.toString()).append("\nRead bytes: ").append(readBytes).append("\n");
            logWarning(warningLog.toString());
         }
      }
   }
}
```